# Is it okey to use lambda in this case?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm trying to figure out a way to loop over a panda DataFrame to generate a new key.
Here's an example of the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"pdb" : ["a", "b"], "beg": [1, 2], "end" : [10, 11]})

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    df['range'] = [list(x) for x in zip(df['beg'], df['end'])]
```

And now I want to create a new key, that basically takes the first and last number of  `df["range"]` and full the list with the numbers in the middle (ie, the first one will be `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`)
So far I think that I should be using something like this, but I could be completely wrong:
 `df["total"] = df["range"].map(lambda x: #and here I should append all the "x" that are betwen df["range"][0] and df["range"][1]`

Here's an example of the result that I'm looking for:

```
  pdb  beg end range  total 
0  a    1   10  1 10  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1  b    2   11  2 11  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

I could use some help with the lambda function, I get really confused with the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with apply

```
df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x : list(range(x['beg'],x['end']+1)),axis=1)
Out[423]: 
0     [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
1    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df['total'] = df['range'].apply(lambda x: [n for n in range(x[0], x[1]+1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your output, you need

```
In [18]: df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x : " ".join(list(map(str,range(x['beg'],x['end']+1)))),axis=1)

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
  pdb  beg  end    range                    new
0   a    1   10  [1, 10]   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1   b    2   11  [2, 11]  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use iterrows then you can do it in the loop itself as follows:

Code :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"pdb" : ["a", "b"], "beg": [1, 2], "end" : [10, 11]})

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    df['range'] = [list(x) for x in zip(df['beg'], df['end'])]
    df['total'] = [range(*x) for x in zip(df['beg'], df['end'])]
```

Output:

```
  pdb  beg  end    range                         total
0   a    1   10  [1, 10]   (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
1   b    2   11  [2, 11]  (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```